# updatepanel not working Url routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I'm running into a bit of an issue. My postbacks are causing my asp.net application pages to jump back to the top of the page even though they are inside update panels.
when i use this routing updatepanel stop working

```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("UProfile", "{ID}", "~/UProfile.aspx");
    }
```

but when i use this code it works fine, but i want the simplest URL

```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("UProfile", "Users/{ID}", "~/UProfile.aspx");
```

how should i solve this problem ? 
I have tried a couple different solutions, that did not work:

1) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

2) http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: By adding this route you are actually targeting root url. Hence this behavior is expected. Either you have to specify the route as  you did in second snippet, or you can try writing Router Constraint which will help asp.net to decide weather to provide it special treatment or skip it. For example if your id is Guid or Integer, add proper constraint and check if it works as per your wish. In this way the constraint will skip the root url surely :)

Comment: is there any example of writing Router Constraint ?

Comment: Yeah you just have to create a class implementing the interface IRouteContraint. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Comment: sorry but i am using webforms not MVC

Comment: You can define constraints in web form application as well .. check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668177(v=vs.100).aspx and http://www.shubho.net/2011/02/aspnet-mvp-url-routing-webforms-part3.html, You can even write regular expression if your constraint is not much complext

Comment: oh my god thanks ! it works now , you saved my day ;) i cant answer ma question :-(
but thanks any way :*

Comment: Cheers :) You can hit like to my comment if it was helpful :) ... Have you created a Constraint by d way?

Comment: I know this is old, but, what changes did you actually make?  I have to fix a webform app and this problem showed up as soon as routing was turned on (I just disabled routing as it no longer helps anymore in SEO - kind of pointless nowadays), but would still like to see an example (they'll make me use routing no matter my opinion eventually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will route will target root Url because there is no any specific identifier to map it properly. I will rather suggest to write a route constraint so you can decide when to use the user details page after validating the passed parameter. 
You can add routers in Asp.net Webforms too. Check the following link.
**http://www.shubho.net/2011/02/aspnet-mvp-url-routing-webforms-part3.html**

The possible solution would be...

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("UProfile",
                                "{ID}",
                                "~/UProfile.aspx",
                                false,
                                new RouteValueDictionary { { "ID", "1" } }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "ID", "[\d]+" } });
```