# update panel dosent work in special solution

Tags: asp.net

I have two projects. In the first project the update panel works correctly but the same code (same page when copy paste) doesn't work and do full post back. My code is simple and is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

In second project I have global.asax with this code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);

}

void RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.Add("Company", new System.Web.Routing.Route("{category}", new CategoryRouteHandler()));
    routes.MapPageRoute("catid","{catid}", "~/Company.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `UpdateMode` to `Conditional`?

Comment: yes I did it but dosent work yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change RegisterRoute like below. More information [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490980/updatepanel-not-working-url-routing)

```
  void RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.Add("Company", new System.Web.Routing.Route("{category}", new CategoryRouteHandler()));
        routes.MapPageRoute("catid", "{catid}", "~/Company.aspx",false);
    }
```

Comment: problem is in this line (when I remove this line update panel work correctly) but adding false,dosent solve problem. in the link say to change to RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("UProfile",
                                "{ID}",
                                "~/UProfile.aspx",
                                false,
                                new RouteValueDictionary { { "ID", "1" } }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "ID", "[\d]+" } });   but I have no RouteValueDirectory class!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```